# Compare the columns in the database with the variables obtained in the python code

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL database using `Python(mysql.connector)`. This is my table:

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+------------+
| id | num1 | num2 | gen | filename   |
+----+-------+-------+--------+------------+
|  1 |    45 |    55 | woman  | vid1.mp4 |
|  2 |    25 |    35 | man    | vid2.mp4 |
|  3 |    45 |    55 | man    | vid3.mp4 |
|  4 |    5 |    15 | woman   | vid4.mp4 |
```

I then get the list below by querying the database:

```
 [(1, 45, 55, 'woman', 'vid1.mp4'), (2, 25, 35, 'man', 'vid2.mp4'),(3, 45, 55, 'man', 'vid3.mp4'),(4, 5, 15, 'woman', 'vid4.mp4')]
```

I get the number and gender in my code and compare it with the num1, num2 and gender entered in the database.
For example:

```
if 25<num<35 and gender =='man':
   filename = 'vid2.mp4'
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you selecting for filename? Are you trying to do other things? Please give an example of the output.

Comment: yes i want to select filename based on num and gender.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a list of data like you have specified here, it is useful to add column names to it.

```
data = [(1, 45, 55, 'woman', 'vid1.mp4') ... ] # This comes from DB
col_names = ['id','num1','num2','gen','filename']
```

Next, iterate over your data in a loop

```
for row in data:
    # row now contains a single value, for instance (1, 45, 55, 'woman', 'vid1.mp4')

    row_dict = dict(zip(col_names, row)) 
    # row_dict is now a dictionary of {'id':1, 'num1':45 ... }

    if row_dict['num1'] == 25:
        print("%s has an num1 of 25!" % row_dict)
```

I hope that this gives you an idea how to iterate over your data and detect certain values are as you expect.

Another options is to use tuple unpacking in the loop

```
for id, num1, num2, gen, filename in data:
    if num1 == 25:
        print ("wow!")
```

Based on your edit:

```
for id, num1, num2, gen, db_filename in data:
    if 25<num1<35 and gen == 'man':
        filename = db_filename
else:
    print("Oh no, file not found")
    filename = None
```

Comment: thanks,but when i print(row_dict) then: {'id': (1, 45, 55, 'woman', 'vid1.mp4'), 'num1': (2, 25, 35, 'man', 'vid2.mp4'), 'gen': (4, 5, 15, 'woman', 'vid4.mp4'), 'num2': (3, 45, 55, 'man', 'vid3.mp4')}

Comment: Whoops! @dafimock - I should have written `dict(zip(col_names, row))` not `... ,data))`. I have edited my example above to resolve this issue.